# El método toString

Tags: java, herencia, override

**¡HOLA!**

Tengo que pasar este test unitario

```
    @Test
    public void testToString() {
        try {
            WrestlerForTesting thunderRosa = new WrestlerForTesting("Melissa Cervantes", LocalDate.of(1986, 7, 22), "Tijuana, Mexico",
                    Gender.FEMALE, 160, 54, "Thunder Rosa", 70, 10, 5, 5, 10);

            assertEquals("THUNDER ROSA" + System.lineSeparator() +
                    "\tBirth name: Melissa Cervantes" + System.lineSeparator() +
                    "\tBorn: 22-07-1986" + System.lineSeparator() +
                    "\t      Tijuana, Mexico" + System.lineSeparator() +
                    "\tSignature: Superkick" + System.lineSeparator() +
                    "\tFinisher: Canadian Destroyer" + System.lineSeparator() +
                    "\tOverall: 0.0", thunderRosa.toString());

        } catch (SuperstarException | WrestlerException ex) {
            fail("There was an error with toString: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

El mensaje de error del test unitario:

```
Expected : Overall: 0.0
Actual   : Overall: 20.0
```

La clase Wrestler sobreescribe el método toString de forma que devuelva lo mismo que Superstar añadiendo a las siguientes líneas (iniciadas con "\t"):

- Signature: S. On S es el valor del atributo signature
- Finisher: F. Donde F es el valor del atributo finisher
- Overall: O. On O es el valor de getOverall.

> El método toString de la clase Superstar, pasa correctamente sus respectivo test unitario.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    
    return ringName.toUpperCase() + System.lineSeparator() +
    "\tBirth name: " + birthName + System.lineSeparator() +
    "\tBorn: " + birthDate.format(dateFormatter) + System.lineSeparator() +
    "\t      " + birthplace;
}
```

> El método toString de la clase Wrestler.

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

        return getRingName().toUpperCase() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tBirth name: " + getBirthName() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tBorn: " + getBirthDate().format(dateFormatter) + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\t      " + getBirthplace() +
                "\tSignature: " + signature + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tFinisher: " + finisher + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tOverall: 0.0" + getOverall();
    }
```

Que tengo mal, como soluciono? Gracias!

**BUEN INICIO DE SEMANA**

Comment: "\tOverall: 0.0" + getOverall(); esto suena raro estas mostrando dos veces el numero?

Comment: Si juntamos tus dos preguntas, da la sensación de que el método getOverall no está funcionando correctamente. Posiblemente también tengas un test que te esté fallando dado esto y tu comentario de MALAMENT en la clase Powerhouse. Aparte de lo que indica gbianchi. ¿No hay un test para ese método?

Comment: El método toString de la clase Wrestler ya está solucionado, gracias!